# How to I position a table on a page without effecting another element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to move a table that I have created without effecting or moving an SVG that I already have coded in. The css positioning that I have right now is :

```
 .table2 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left:800px;

    }
```

This positions my table where I want it to go, but is pushing everything else that I have already on the page. How can I do this where it does not effect any other element positioning?

Here is my .js:

```
  <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.counties').on("click",function(e){ 
   $('.table2').fadeIn();
   });
 });

 </script>
```

and this is my table:

```
<table class="table2" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
<tr>
<td><pre><font color="696969"face="Century Gothic">###### CHILDREN NEED A GIFT
            IN THIS COUNTY</font></pre></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button><font color="696969"face="Century Gothic">Volunteer</font> 
</button><button><font color="696969"face="Century Gothic">Donate</font> 
</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This is what is being moved because of the table position:

```
  <path class="counties"
 style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill- 
  rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke- 
  linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke- 
  dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none"
  d="m 471.60261,246.44442 29.99111,-0.99619 8.36129,-11.40059 
  -0.16978,-0.49813 0.58508,-0.68252 h 1.28346 l 2.45362,1.10686 
   4.6997,5.90324 5.05827,15.71735 1.37784,5.53421 0.11332,0.44279 
   1.52883,11.1239 0.41524,4.8333 0.26423,10.23838 0.50959,34.0174 
   -24.17783,3.63415 -6.11526,0.16628 -15.1371,-10.57045 -25.87655,4.99926 
   -21.25234,27.68986 -9.45597,-12.37832 -7.04008,-9.31609 9.4371,-6.8256 
    10.94705,-12.63657 v -0.59033 l -1.00034,-1.73412 33.1997,-57.77781"
    id="Monmouth"
    inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

Comment: Use CSS property `position: absolute` and `top:`, `left:` instead of margins

Comment: yes, i have already tried that. But I have the table on a fadeIn() on click, and when I use the position: absolute route, the table will fad in, and then immediately vanish.

Comment: Show us your fadeIn() function and the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Okay i did that

Comment: Would be awesome if you placed it as a snippet so that we could watch it. Or give us a link on Codepen or jsfiddle